# Wordpress plugin development - get all active widgets

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I am developing a wordpress plugin that creates a widget that would act upon another widget. I have searched but cant seem to find (if it exists) a hook that would give details of all active instances of widgets. any help would be appreciated if you have come across this. thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`get_option('sidebars_widgets')` gives you an associative array that contains a list of widgets for each sidebar plus a list of all inactive widgets.

`get_option('widget_widgetname')` will give you an associative array that contains the settings of all instances of your widget.

Comment: get_option('widget_widgetname') not working to my custom widget, only get_option('widget_text'), get_option('widget_rss') and get_option('widget_categories'), but not get_option('widget_mycustomwidget')

Comment: Might be because i added it as a plugin? but even if the widget is active its not working, i tried get_option('widget_calendar') and it returns the title name,but my custom widget is not returning anything

Answer (score 1):

for example to remove a widget from a page

```
add_filter( 'sidebars_widgets', 'disable_widgets' );

function disable_widgets( $sidebars_widgets ) {
global $qode_options_proya;
    //print_r($sidebars_widgets);//gives a list of widgets
    if(is_admin()){return $sidebars_widgets;}
    if(get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'hide_allwidgets_checkbox', true )=="on"){return false; }


    if(get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'hide_footer', true )=="on"){unset($sidebars_widgets["footer_column_1"]);}
    if(get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'hide_topmenu_checkbox', true )=="on"){unset($sidebars_widgets["header_top"]); }
    return $sidebars_widgets;
}
```

This might vary depending on your theme, so use ***print_r($sidebars_widgets);*** to verify the widgets available on your case

Answer (score 1):

You can get all the active widgets of sidebar as follows::

```
$sidebars_widgets = get_option( 'sidebars_widgets' );
```

it will give you an associative array containing a list of widgets per sidebar and a list of all inactive widgets.